# Should a Cython memory view of indexes be of type Py_ssize_t or int?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cython, cpython

I have cython code that takes a  2d `numpy.ndarray` of data (`M`) and a `numpy.ndarray` of indexes (`Ixs`). It loops through the entries of `Ixs` and uses the values `ix` of `Ixs` to index columns of `M`. See the code below:

```
def foo(double[:, ::1] M, int[:, ::1] Ixs):
    cdef int rows = M.shape[0]
    cdef int cols = M.shape[1]
    cdef Py_ssize_t c, r
    for c in range(rows):
        for r in range(cols):
            ix = Ixs[c, r]
            dosomething(M[c, ix])
```

I know that I am supposed to use `Py_ssize_t` as a type for indexes (I have read it is to accommodate for 64 bit architectures) but right now I am using a memory view of type `int`... In this case I don't see a way to create a `numpy.ndarray` of `Py_ssize_t` so that `ix` is `Py_ssize_t`.

What is the correct way to write this cython code? Is there any problem in using `int`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing to note, you will want to type `ix`

Your code as written will work OK, `M[c, ix]` will cast ix from an `int` to `Py_ssize_t`, which should always be a safe conversion.

That said, you can and probably should have your indexer array be of `Py_ssize_t`.  The corresponding numpy type is `np.intp`

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html

Comment: So let's say that I cast it in python to np.intp (`Ixs = Ixs.atype(np.intp)`) then I rewrite this function as: `def foo(double[:, ::1] M, Py_ssize_t[:, ::1] Ixs):` right?

Comment: Yes, although ideally `Ixs` typed intp at creation to avoid the cast.

Comment: Of course, but in my case it will be an output of a scikit learn function.